# in javascript, why does a variable 'run' code?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, `a = alert("why?")` does the same thing as just `alert("why?)`.

Why?
And what is the name of that feature of the language?

Comment: Check if this SO post helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380382/javascript-assign-variable-to-alert

Comment: thanks! the description in the answer of how the code is parsed helps clarify things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling a function, which does whatever the function is defined to do, and then assigning the return value of that function to the variable.

Practically every programming language works like this. You need to learn basic programming concepts.

This is called *assigning the result of a function to a variable*, and is a common way to use functions. If you just do:

```
alert("Foo");
```

that's called *calling a function*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... re: "You need to learn basic programming concepts" Lol :) Yes, well, that's what I'm trying to do. More specifically what I am trying to do is acquire the vocabulary. To rephrase my question: "what do you call it when you use the alert function in conjunction with a variable, as opposed to 'on its own' ?"  Of course that assuming there are in fact specific terms. In any event, once I identify the terminology, then it is much easier to search for explanations and learn those basic concepts!

Comment: There's nothing special about the `alert` function. `a = alert(...)` is no different from `a = Math.random()`. They both call a function, and assign the result to a variable.

Comment: sorry - not talking about the `alert` function in particular. It could be `setTimeout` or whatever... my question is regarding the terminology difference between using the function 'with a variable' rather than 'on its own'.

Comment: It's called "assigning the result of a function to a variable"

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. In this case it would seem there is no generic 'handle' for that move.

Comment: Yeah. It's not something that comes up in discussion, so it doesn't really need a name. Some early languages had a distinction between _procedures_ (which just perform an action and don't return anything) and _functions_ (which return a value). But most languages used these days don't bother.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are calling a function when you pass in a parameter. For example, if you wanted `a` to actually be a variable that points to the alert function, then you would do something like this:

```
var a = alert;
```

Ideally, whenever you pass in the parameter, the function gets called. Then you could do something like:

```
a("Why?");
```

And it would get called.

Answer (score 1):

[The RHS of an assignment is an expression](http://tomcopeland.blogs.com/EcmaScript.html#prod9).

A function invocation is an expression. It is executed and then its return value is assigned to the identifier on the LHS.

```
<variable> = <exp>
```