# function expression versus directly calling

Tags: javascript, function, closures

why different outcomes when calling the function directly versus making it a functional expression and then calling the variable?

```
function makeFunc() {
  var name = "Mozilla";
  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName;
}

console.log(makeFunc());
makeFunc(); //no alert

var myFunc = makeFunc();
console.log(myFunc);
myFunc(); //Yes alert
```

Comment: Because the first one never calls `displayName`, while the second one does (indirectly).

Comment: That's a closure. If you don't store the returned value which is a function and don't call the returned function then the code makes no sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380382/javascript-assign-variable-to-alert

Comment: @DarkFalcon can you explain the 'indirectly calling the displayName function process' for me? That'd be my answer!!

Comment: @Vohuman Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the function's return

```js
function makeFunc() {
    var name = "Mozilla";
    function displayName() {
        alert(name);
    }
    return displayName;
}
makeFunc()(); // alert!
```